# Java count all the values of an array and store it in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to count values of an array and keep it into an array.In php we do so using array_count_values.

```
    $a=array("A","Cat","Dog","A","Dog");
    print_r(array_count_values($a));
```

Output :

```
    Array ( [A] => 2 [Cat] => 1 [Dog] => 2 )
```

I want to do so in java.

```
Map<String, String[]> map = request.getParameterMap();
String[] wfBlockIds     = map.get("wf_block_id[]");
        Arrays.stream(wfBlockIds)
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s))
          .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k+" => "+v.size() + " --" + v));
```

Output of the Java Code is :

```
1469441140125 => 3 --[1469441140125, 1469441140125, 1469441140125]
1469441126299 => 2 --[1469441126299, 1469441126299]
```

How can I will get equivalent result as array_count_values() which will be in an array.

Comment: What do you want the output type to be? An array of what?

Comment: output will be an array that will contain element of wfBlockIds array.Array ( [A] => 2 [Cat] => 1 [Dog] => 2 )

Comment: Please update your question instead of putting infos in comments.

Comment: Arrays in Java can only have int indices, so what you are requesting is not possible, perhaps a Map<String,Integer> will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (String s : array) {
    if (map.containsKey(s)) {
        Integer v = map.get(s);
        map.put(s, v+1);
    } else {
        map.put(s, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Altough Java arrays only have int indices, you can achieve the same functionnality as in PHP with a Map.

The following code produces something similar to `array_count_values`

```
Map<String, Long> result = Stream.of("A", "Cat", "Dog", "A", "Dog")
                                 .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), counting()));
System.out.println(result); //prints {A=2, Cat=1, Dog=2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, but the String array that you are getting from request params contains 3 * "1469441126299" and 2 * "1469441140125";
Print out your request.getParameterMap() and you will see that

Comment: try to use request.getParameter("wf_block_id[]") without calling the parameterMap